# Finding exact match of letters from a link occuring only once

Tags: javascript, regex

I created some code to add some text depending on the language found in the link but I have a problem with matching exactly the language because the pattern is too simple. I need to find exactly what comes after .com and nothing else. I tried this `/.*\/\/.*?\/(\S{2})/gm` expression but, it isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

```js
//find the url of the page
// const findUrl = window.location.href;
const findUrl = "https://www.example.com/fr/Pages/examplefr.html";
console.log(findUrl);

const langs = [{
    pattern: /en/, //find strictly only the EN
    text: "A very long text in English to replace existing text"
  },
  {
    pattern: /fr/, //find strictly only the FR
    text: "Je ne parle pas français"
  },
  {
    pattern: /es/, //find strictly only the ES
    text: "No hablo español."
  }
];

let found = false;
for (let i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
  if (findUrl.match(langs[i].pattern)) {
    console.log("The match has been found!");
    let findP = document.getElementById("texts").querySelectorAll("p");
    findP[0].innerText = langs[i].text;
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (!found) {
  console.log("The match was not found");
}
```

```html
<div id="texts">
 <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like `/\.com\/(\w{2})\//` to get the language and compare it as a text. This would be easier if your `langs` object was of the format `{[lang: string]: string}`.

```js
const findUrl = "https://www.example.com/fr/Pages/examplefr.html";
console.log(findUrl);

const langs = {
  "en": "A very long text in English to replace existing text",
  "fr": "Je ne parle pas français",
  "es": "ANo hablo español.",
};

if (!findLanguage()) console.log("The match was not found");

function findLanguage() {
  var result = /\.com\/(\w{2})\//.exec(findUrl);
  if (result && result[1] in langs) {
    console.log("The match has been found!");
    document.querySelector("#texts p").textContent = langs[result[1]];
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="texts">
  <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the 'lang pattern' from the original URL and find the object in your array that matches this pattern:

```js
//find the url of the page
// const findUrl = window.location.href;
const findUrl = "http://enmicasa.com/es/Pages/examplefr.com/fr";
console.log(findUrl);

const langs = [{
    pattern: "en", //find strictly only the EN
    text: "A very long text in English to replace existing text"
  },
  {
    pattern: "fr", //find strictly only the FR
    text: "Je ne parle pas français"
  },
  {
    pattern: "es", //find strictly only the ES
    text: "No hablo español."
  }
];
const myLang = langs.find(obj => findUrl.replace(/.*\.com\/(.+?)\/.*/,"$1") === obj.pattern);
if (myLang){
    console.log("The match has been found!");
    let findP = document.getElementById("texts").querySelectorAll("p");
    findP[0].innerText = myLang.text;
}else {
  console.log("The match was not found");
}
```

```html
<div id="texts">
 <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Note: I changed the URL to test one with some complication on it

Answer (score -2):

Hi check this snippet!

---

### How it works

1. We are iterating trought all values of the langs object using .map `langs.map(e => ...)`
2. We are checking if the **langs pattern** + Regex matches the URI using `findUrl.match(new RegExp(`.*.com${e.pattern}.*`, "g")`
3. We extract the matching value from the array using `.filter(e => !!e).pop()`

```js
const findUrl = "https://www.example.com/fr/Pages/examplefr.html";

const langs = [{
    pattern: /en/, //find strictly only the EN
    text: "A very long text in English to replace existing text"
  },
  {
    pattern: /fr/, //find strictly only the FR
    text: "Je ne parle pas français"
  },
  {
    pattern: /es/, //find strictly only the ES
    text: "No hablo español."
  }
];

const result = (
  langs.map(e => !!findUrl.match(new RegExp(`.*\.com${e.pattern}.*`, "g")) ? e.text : null).filter(e => !!e).pop()
);
texts.innerText = result;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="texts">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `!!` inside the `if` statement. And you are better off using `some` instead of `map` to stop once the first one is found.

Comment: Yeah but it is a smooth way to convert any datatype (array in this case) to a boolean. This is a (unnecesary) but common procedure. @nickzoum

Comment: The if block will do the conversion anyway.

Comment: Not mine downvote (just revisited this thread to delete my answer which was downvoted too).However, I may come up with a couple of reasons your post may get downvoted and why it isn't a ***smooth solution*** at all.Using `match()` and casting its output to boolean is overkill there's a `RegExp.prototype.test()`. Another one may be the fact, you iterate source array unnecessarily twice with `map()` and `filter()`, where simple `Array.prototype.find()` would work much better exiting the (first) loop, once the (single, if recall the question statement) match was found.

Comment: Yet another one is your code formatted absolutely awful. Those hints won't remove those downvotes but may help you to avoid further ones ;)

Comment: I haven't downvoted, (haven't upvoted either for the same reasons stated in the above comment). The thing is that people that have downvoted this don't get notified when the post gets edited so they wont see the improvements you may have added.